# MS Visual Studio can use C++/CLI or MFC to create Windows GUI Apps, what does C++ Builder (RAD Studio) use?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Recently a youtube channel called codebeauty introduced me to the C++ Builder (RAD Studio). This is  a program from Embarcadero. This is not created by Microsoft it seems.

Now I am a little confused here. If C++ Builder (RAD Studio) does not use C++/CLI .Net, and does not use MFC then how does it actually get a C++ GUI to work? Also, how come people that want to create GUI apps in C++ don't use C++ Builder (RAD Studio) since this is an old program and must stable by now and is supposed to be a easier and quicker alternative to MFC? This is a program with a long history, but I never heard about it from anywhere or anyone before.

Comment: Builder uses straight C++, and uses the same VCL (Visual Component Library) that Delphi uses, which is much more extensive than MFC and much easier to use. The IDE is extremely well done, and I prefer it quite a bit over VS. The flexibility of the VCL is that you can use both Builder-developed components and those developed for Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

> Recently a youtube channel called codebeauty introduced me to the C++ Builder (RAD Studio). This is a program from Embarcadero. This is not created by Microsoft it seems.

No, C++Builder is not made by Microsoft.  It was originally created by Borland in 1997, as a C++ counterpart to Delphi, which was also created by Borland.  In 2006, Borland spawned a separate company named CodeGear to continue development of Delphi and C++Builder.  In 2008, CodeGear was sold to Embarcadero.

> Now I am a little confused here. If C++ Builder (RAD Studio) does not use C++/CLI .Net, and does not use MFC then how does it actually get a C++ GUI to work?

The same way that other vendors do.  C++Builder uses its own class frameworks, known as VCL (Windows-only) and FMX (cross-platform) <sup>1</sup>, which internally call into underlying OS frameworks, for instance Windows' native GDI and UI Controls APIs.

<sup>1: which are largely written in Pascal rather than C++, so they can also be used in Delphi, which shares the same IDE architecture with C++Builder.  There is a certain level of binary compatibility between C++Builder and Delphi so they can share libraries with each other.</sup>

> Also, how come people that want to create GUI apps in C++ don't use C++ Builder (RAD Studio)

Partly because it is just not widely known to/used by developers who weren't around in the late 1990s/early 2000s, when C++Builder was at its peak.  Nowadays, Embarcadero's main focus is on Delphi, with many features introduced in Delphi not making it into C++Builder until years after, if ever.

Partly because it is quite expensive. Until recent years, there was no free Community edition available, or even free command-line compilers.  It was geared more towards professional developers and universities, not hobbyists.

Partly because until recent years, it was largely based on outdated C++ technologies.  At its peak, C++Builder only supported C++98.  During the 2000s onward, as C++ continued to evolve, the old Borland compilers just didn't keep up, and so most 3rd party library/framework vendors dropped support for them.  Also, Borland/Embarcadero used to be on the C++ standard committee (not sure if they still are), but could never seem to get their proprietary compiler extensions standardized (VCL/FMX rely heavily on them).  But, in more recent years, Embarcadero has been pushing C++11, C++14, and C++17 compliance into their newer C++ compilers (which are based on Clang), so this trend is starting to reverse a little.

There are a lot of other reasons.  Those of us who do use C++Builder, love it (or at least tolerate its faults).  Those who don't use it, well they have their own reasons or not starting with it.

> since this is an old program and must stable by now

The VCL framework is quite mature and stable, yes.  But C++Builder as a product has actually had a pretty turbulent and disappointing history when it comes to features and stability, compared to Delphi.

C++Builder was actually End-Of-Life'd in 2002 (another reason for library/framework authors to stop supporting it), and then resurrected in 2004.  Before that time, C++Builder and Delphi were pretty much on par with each other.  But during the time that C++Builder was EOL, Delphi migrated to a whole new IDE architecture, and has been pushing out new features ever since.  When C++ was resurrected into that same IDE, it has not quite been as stable as it was in its old IDE, and it has always been playing catchup with Delphi.

To this day, the IDE experience of C++Builder has quite a number of bugs, bad performance, missing/incomplete features, and overall inconsistent/compatibility issues between its various C++ compilers, of which it now has many <sup>2</sup>.

<sup>2: at the time of this writing, 5 supported platforms, with 1 compiler each, except for 32bit Windows, which has 3 compilers.</sup>

> and is supposed to be a easier and quicker alternative to MFC?

That, I would generally agree with, yes.  Rapid GUI development has always been a high point for it (same with Delphi).

> This is a program with a long history, but I never heard about it from anywhere or anyone before.

Read up about [C++Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder), [Borland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland), and [CodeGear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeGear) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Actually C++ Builder 10.4.2 is a big step forward in stability. Finally.

Comment: @MikeVersteeg I wouldn't know, I haven't used it yet. I just go off what I read in the various C++Builder/Delphi communities.